# Ошибка в aiogram при добавлении в url inline кнопки ссылки на юзера тг

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Всем доброго дня!
При добавлении в url inlinekeyboardbutton ссылки на пользователя возникает ошибка `aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Button_user_invalid`
Если поменять ссылку на на обычную, например google.com, то кнопка работает. Код кнопки:

```
command_help_btn = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Администратор', url=f'tg://user?id={admin_id}')
```

admin_id точно правильный.
Полный трейс ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tgbot2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tgbot2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tgbot2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tgbot2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tgbot2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tgbot2\handlers\client\default.py", line 55, in command_help
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "☎️ Нажмите на кнопку ниже для открытия поддержки", reply_markup=command_help_kb)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tgbot2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 339, in send_message
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tgbot2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 231, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tgbot2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tgbot2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tgbot2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 141, in detect
    raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Button_user_invalid
```

Comment: Попробовал у себя, не обнаружил проблем

Comment: Можете вставить полный трейс ошибки?

Comment: Полный трейс добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ скрывался на поверхности, а точнее в документации aiogram.

url : string

Optional. HTTP or tg:// URL to be opened when the button is pressed. Links tg://user?id=<user_id> ***can be used to mention a user by their ID without using a username***, if this is allowed by their privacy settings.

Т.е. ссылаться на id можно только в том случае, если у пользователя нет юзернейма, в противном случае, необходима ссылка вида [https://t.me/{username}](https://t.me/%7Busername%7D) .